# TableViewCell Background Color Gradient

Tags: ios, uitableview

So currently I´m working with a TableViewController but I want it to be like a gradient tableview on each cell as shown in the image

[image]

Is there any good way to accomplish this based on the size of the array that I´m filling the table with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to interpolate between two colors you could interpolate between each RGB color component (You could also do this with HSB).

Define a starting color and ending color. I chose a tuple representation:

```
typealias Color = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)

let startColor: Color = (red: 0.0/255, green: 114.0/255.0, blue: 96.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let endColor: Color = (red: 10.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 161.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Calculate the number of steps and the step size for each color component:

```
var data = [/* ... */]
let steps = data.count > 1 ? CGFloat(data.count - 1) : 1.0
let rStep = (endColor.red - startColor.red) / steps,
    gStep = (endColor.green - startColor.green) / steps,
    bStep = (endColor.blue - startColor.blue) / steps,
    aStep = (endColor.alpha - startColor.alpha) / steps
```

Finally, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let rowIdx = CGFloat(indexPath.row)
myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: startColor.red + rowIdx * rStep, green: startColor.green + rowIdx * gStep, blue: startColor.blue + rowIdx * bStep , alpha: startColor.alpha + rowIdx * aStep)
```

If your cell count changes you'd of course want to recalculate the step size for each color component.

The result in a playground:

[image]

Comment: awesome answer thanks! just one more question the second step, all of those calculation where do i declare them?, I´m asking this because it´s throwing me an error "Instance member 'categories' cannot be used on type 'HomeVC' "

Comment: @CesarMtz You could keep each step variable as an instance variable on your view controller and update it if your data count changes. In that case you could put the calculation in a function called by `viewDidLoad`. The only thing is you wouldn't want that code to be called for _every_ `cellForRowAtIndexpath` since the step sizes only change when when your data count changes, therefore you'd be doing unnecessary computation.